# pivot_longer() with haven variable labels

Tags: r, tidyr, r-haven

I have a tibble whose columns are labelled using `haven`, like so:

```r
library(tibble)
library(tidyr)
library(labelled)

tibble(
  id = 101:102,
  var_1 = c(1, 2),
  var_2 = c(3, 4)
) %>%
  set_variable_labels(var_1 = "Variable 1", var_2 = "Variable 2") -> tbl
```

I would like to `pivot_longer()` `var_1` and `var_2` but would like its variable labels rather than its variable names to end up in the `name` column. Is there a way to do this that's less clunky than

```r
tbl |> 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-id) |> 
  mutate(
    name = forcats::fct_recode(
      name,
      # flip the name -> label mapping
      !!!setNames(names(var_label(tbl)), var_label(tbl))
    )
  )
```

Comment: You can at least drop both `unlist()` calls.

Comment: You're right. So done!

Answer (score 2):

Here is a slightly different suggestion, not sure if it helps;

first rename the columns using an 'inverted' named vector.. then cast to long.

```
library(tidyverse)
temp <- unlist(var_label(tbl))
tbl %>%
  rename(all_of(setNames(names(temp), temp))) %>% 
  tidyr::pivot_longer(-id)
```